# Materialize CSS Equal Column/Card Height: Responsive card-content height

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and Materialize CSS for it's responsive grid system, and while that works great, i'm having issues with cards with unequal heights within a row.

I believe rows will always have the same height with the Materialize grid system, but card height will adjust to fit content.

I have two cards within a row, each having their own separate column, and I would like for their heights to remain the same. The row's height will be defined by the largest card (I think).

I could set both cards to have a height of 100% (I think), so that the shorter card would increase in height to match the taller card, but there is a problem:

The shorter card is divided into three sections: a photo, a card-content section with words, and a card-action section that has a link and is separated by an underline. By increasing the cards height through CSS i'm increasing the card-height by increasing the card-action section's height, which looks awful. I would like the card-content section to grow to match the taller card's height.

I'm thinking I can accomplish this through javascript/typescript (i'm using angular), by increasing the css height of the shorter card's card-content section  by the difference of the two card's height.

The problem is, that I'm not sure when I should be calling the function to make this change. An adjustment needs to be made upon loading up the webpage, but also, whenever the browser is resized.

I tried using the Angular onInit life cycle hook to check the stylings of the two card elements, but I believe no styling takes place until after the onInit hook.

How can I call a function to readjust the card heights immediately after Materialize does it's work?

Am I overthinking this?